# Single Query to retrieve count of the employees

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have an employee table with the following fields

> employee(id, name, joiningDate, salary, dept)

I would like to retrieve count of all the employees who joined the company in past 1day, 2days, 3days and 4days in each department. Please see the result I need in the below link.

> Sample result:
>   [image: Sample Results]

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it in the past 24 hours, between 24 and 48 hours, etc...

```
SELECT dept,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN joiningDate BETWEEN SYSDATE - 1 AND SYSDATE     THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS day1,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN joiningDate BETWEEN SYSDATE - 2 AND SYSDATE - 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS day2,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN joiningDate BETWEEN SYSDATE - 3 AND SYSDATE - 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS day3,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN joiningDate BETWEEN SYSDATE - 4 AND SYSDATE - 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS day4,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN joiningDate BETWEEN SYSDATE - 5 AND SYSDATE - 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS day5
FROM   Employee
GROUP BY dept;
```

If you want it yesterday, 2 days ago, 3 days ago, etc then wrap `TRUNC()` around each instance of `SYSDATE`.

Comment: Is it possible to exclude weekends from the counts?

Comment: Something like: `COUNT( CASE WHEN joiningDate BETWEEN TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - CASE WHEN TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'D' ) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 3 END AND TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - CASE WHEN TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'D' ) > 1 THEN 0 ELSE 2 END THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS Day1` However, beware `NLS_TERRITORY` will influence the value the `'D'` parameter returns - see here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2207756

Answer (score 1):

The following should get you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT DEPT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(JOININGDATE) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(JOININGDATE) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(JOININGDATE) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(JOININGDATE) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day4,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(JOININGDATE) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS day5
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY DEPT
ORDER BY DEPT;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d1f8d/2)

Comment: Is it possible to exclude weekends from the counts?

Comment: I expect you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

If we have pivot tag then why not use `pivot`?

```
select * from (
    select dept, trunc(sysdate)-trunc(joiningDate) dt
      from employee where joiningDate >= trunc(sysdate)-5)
  pivot (count(1) for dt in (1 day1, 2 day2, 3 day3, 4 day4, 5 day5)) 
  order by dept
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b42902/1)